# Difference between the meaning of Nachweis and Erfassung as used in scientific context

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, usage, technical-terminology

In chemistry, there is a term called "limit of detection" and the German literature equivalent is called Nachweisgrenze. Basically, it indicates the smallest quantity which can be detected.

However, there is another closely used term in German whose English equivalent does not exist. It is called Erfassungsgrenze [see Terminology](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/de/ch/16/bbz/bbz_addin.vlu/Page/vsc/de/ch/16/bbz/bbz_addin_nachweis.vscml/Supplement/2.html).

What is the subtle difference in the meaning of Nachweis and Erfassung in German and what would be a closest possible word in English for Erfassungsgrenze?

If we check Linguee, both Nachweisgrenze and Erfassungsgrenze are translated as "detection limit" which are essentially correct in the scientific context but when would someone use Nachweis vs. Erfassung?

Comment: At the given link there are two different formulae to calulate _Nachweisgrenze_ and _Erfassungsgrenze_, so it depends on the context what was asked for when to use either or both.

Comment: Thanks but I am asking about the difference in meaning (as in common usage), their statistical definitions are clear. If I were to translate Erfassungsgrenze in English, what would be the closest word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the verbs from which the nouns are derived:

- nachweisen = to prove, to verify, to provide evidence
- erfassen = to determine, to register, to find out
- bestimmen = to identify, to determine

Here are the translations of the definitions from the website you linked to:

- **Nachweisgrenze = verification limit**

  > Die *Nachweisgrenze* ist die kleinste Menge Gehalt einer Probe, die mit einem α-Fehler von 5% und einem β-Fehler von 50% qualitativ nachgewiesen werden kann.
  >
  > The *verification limit* is the smallest amount of content in a sample that can be qualitatively detected with an α error of 5% and a β error of 50%.
- **Erfassungsgrenze = registration limit**

  > Die *Erfassungsgrenze* ist die kleinste Menge Gehalt einer Probe, die mit einem α-Fehler von 5% und einem β-Fehler von 5% (qualitativ) nachgewiesen werden kann.
  >
  > The *registration limit* is the smallest amount of content in a sample that can be detected with an α error of 5% and a β error of 5% (qualitative).
- **Bestimmungsgrenze = limit of quantification**

  > Die *Bestimmungsgrenze* ist die kleinste Menge Gehalt einer Probe, die bei vorgegebener statistischer Sicherheit und maximal zugelassener relativer Abweichung quantitativ bestimmbar ist.
  >
  > The *limit of quantification* is the smallest amount of content in a sample that can be quantified with a given statistical certainty and maximum permissible relative deviation.

Comment: Thank you. Would you consider nachweisen and erfassen as synonyms in common daily use? The definition of Nachweisgrenze is equivalent to "limit of detection" in English which is very well established term. The quantity Erfassungsgrenze does not have a name in English. I think registration limit could be the closest rendition of this quantity.

Comment: @M.Farooq: No *erfassen* means *to record* (to store data, to write down something) while *nachweisen*  means *to detect* (Is there something or is there nothing?)

Comment: So I registration limit is perhaps the closest English equivalent, may be one can say "Recording Limit.", i.e., this is the concentration which an instrument can "reliable" record or register.